# How do I correctly use a Javascript function that has an async call in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a Javascript function that returns a boolean value. One of the lines of code in the function invokes a REST call. I didn't realize that call was going to be asynchronous when I coded it. So, basically, the method always returns 'false' when I do something like:

```
if(isDataValid()) ...
```

I could move the actions in the calling function to the success function, but I was trying to create a reusable method. I'm using jQuery and Everest. I have not learned anything about Promises yet and I'm fairly new to callback programming.

Here's boiled down version of my method:

```js
function isDataValid(){

    // Read data from Local Storage

    // Create object from data

    // Flag variable to capture result
    var isValid = null;

    restClient
        .read('/my/url', model)
        .done(function(response)
            {    
                // 'Good' response, set flag to true
                isValid = true;
            })
        .fail(function(response)
            {   
                // 'Bad' response, set flag to false
                isValid = false;
            });

    return isValid;
}
```

How should I make an async call and return true/false?

Comment: You simply cannot. If any part of the stack is asynchronous, everything must be written with async in mind (either via callbacks or promises). You cannot call the function and expect to be able to get the response synchronously.

Comment: Create your "reusable method" and invoke it from the success function passing `invalid` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Function should be marked as `async` in order for `await` to be used inside.

Since you didn't use response, I removed it.
If you need response, then

```
var response = await restClient.read('/my/url/', model);
```

You should use try/catch to handle errors.
Here is the end result:

```
async function isDataValid(){

   var isValid = null;

   try {
       await restClient.read('/my/url', model);
       isValid = true;
   } catch(err) {
       isValid = false;
   }

   return isValid;
}
```

In the end to call `isDataValid` you should also use `await` in front of the function call. So it will looks like that:

```
if(await isDataValid()) { ... }
```

Since `await` can be used only inside `async` functions, function where `isDataValid` is called should be also marked as `async`. This way you should update all the chain of function calls to be used with `await`.

Comment: That doesn't help with calling the function as `if(isDataValid())` though.

Comment: @Felix you're right, but changing it to `if(await isDataValid())` will fix the problem

Comment: Only if the statement is in an `async` function. All I am saying is that your suggestion is only part of the solution. Maybe you want to edit your answer and include the other part (how to call the function).

Comment: `async` / `await` are not too much young for use in production?

Comment: @FelixKling Agree with you, will update it now

Comment: @Andrea async/await is now supported by Node.js runtime - so it's fine, for frontend you should use Babel to transpile code, since async/await is not supported by most of the browsers.